# how to write Mysql query to get data from database based on date?

Tags: java, mysql

My Database table is::

```
attendence date     admission number         attendence

  2013-10-2         LSTM-0008/2013-2014      present

 2013-10-19         LSTM-0008/2013-2014      absent

  2013-10-20         LSTM-0008/2013-2014      present
```

above one is my database table.

i want to display table like this here totalworkingdays is total of present and absent of that month based on database table:

```
 MonthName     totalWorkingDays     Present     absent

 october            3                  2          1
```

i wrote mysql query like this:

```
select distinct
    monthname(attendencedate) as monthname,
    count(*) as totalworkingdays
from  lstms_attendence where
    attendencedate> '2013-10-01' and attendencedate<'2013-10-31'
    and addmissionno='LSTM-0008/2013-2014'
GROUP BY
    monthname(attendencedate),
    sum(CASE WHEN attendence = 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as present,
    SUM(CASE WHEN attendence = 'absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absent
FROM lstms_attendence
WHERE addmissionno = 'LSTM-0008/2013-2014'
GROUP BY monthname(attendencedate);
```

i got error like::

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as present,SUM(CASE WHEN attendence = 'absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absent  FRO' at line 1
(0 ms taken)

Any one give me suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot use `AS` in `GROUB BY`, this has no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to put query always in more readable way.

The need to scroll is repulsive.

It's a little bit mixed up

Several FROM and GROUP BY clauses...

It should look more like

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    monthname(attendencedate) as monthname,
    count(*) as totalworkingdays,
    sum(CASE WHEN attendence = 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as present,
    SUM(CASE WHEN attendence = 'absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absent
FROM  lstms_attendence
WHERE
    attendencedate> '2013-10-01' and attendencedate<'2013-10-31'
    and addmissionno='LSTM-0008/2013-2014'
GROUP BY
    monthname(attendencedate)
```

AFAIR you must not put `AS` in GROUP BY clause. That was what MySQL was telling you.

PS. not tested